# scipy cubic spline with really large y values

Tags: scipy, spline

I am doing some lane detection as a fun project and I am trying to create a cubic spline to represent the lane.  However, when I use the scipy CubicSpline function I get some absurdly large values.

Here is my code:

```
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


rows = img_size[0] # width
height = left_lane.shape[0]
y_values = [0, height/2, height]

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(left_lane, cmap='gray')
splines = []

particle = particles[0]
cx = [particle[0], particle[1], particle[2]]
cy = [y_values[0], y_values[1], y_values[2]]

points = zip(cx, cy)
points = sorted(points, key=lambda point: point[0])
x1, y1 = zip(*points)

x1 = np.asarray(x1)
y1 = np.asarray(y1)
s = CubicSpline(x1, y1)

new_x = np.arange(min(x1), max(x1), 0.1)
new_y = s(new_x)
plt.plot(new_x, new_y)

plt.show()
```

Here is the output:

[image: plotted cubic spline]

Here is the original image with the control points plotted:

[image: original image with control points]

I don't understand why the spline algorithm is giving me such large values for such a simple spline.  So, what is the issue here?  Bad values?  Incorrect usage of cubic spline?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the spline is going vertical in this image which means that the x value isn't in always increasing order (e.g. 2nd control > 1st control point).  So, when I sorted my lists something like this could happen (2, 1, 3).  Then, scipy has to use some huge coefficients to fit this spline.

The fix was to flip the axis so that y is now the x axis.  Now the sorting doesn't cause the any weird ordering of the control points.

```
cx = [particle[0], particle[1], particle[2]]
cy = [y_values[0], y_values[1], y_values[2]]

# Sort particles in increasing x order
points = zip(cx, cy)
points = sorted(points, key=lambda point: point[1])
x1, y1 = zip(*points)

x1 = np.asarray(x1)
y1 = np.asarray(y1)
s = CubicSpline(y1, x1)

new_x = np.arange(min(y1), max(y1), 0.1)
new_y = s(new_x)
plt.plot(new_y, new_x)
plt.plot(cx, cy, '.')
```